# How to extract the name of an iconized data file from the icon

Tags: iconize

I have stored curated data in several iconized files.  The names given to the icons contain identifying information that I would like to extract when I use that data.  How can I do that?

Comment: `Last /@ iconizedfiles`?

Comment: When you say 'iconized file' - do you mean you've imported the data and it is in your notebook as an `IconizedObject`? If that's the case I don't know a clean way to get the name out.